# How to increment field value count using MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a student attendance table.

**Fields/data sample**

```
id | studid | smonth | syear | total_p | total_a
1  |   20   |   08   | 2015  |   1     |   0
2  |   21   |   08   | 2015  |   0     |   1
3  |   22   |   08   | 2015  |   1     |   0
```

Those are the first entered values. Then I again enter values for the same students (20,21,22) for the same month and year. All are present=1

**Fields/data sample**

```
id | studid | smonth | syear | total_p | total_a
1  |   20   |   08   | 2015  |   2     |   0
2  |   21   |   08   | 2015  |   1     |   1
3  |   22   |   08   | 2015  |   2     |   0
```

And I again enter values for the same students for the same month and year. All are present=1 so I want

**Fields/data sample**

```
id | studid | smonth | syear | total_p | total_a
1  |   20   |   08   | 2015  |   3     |   0
2  |   21   |   08   | 2015  |   2     |   1
3  |   22   |   08   | 2015  |   3     |   0
```

What is the code for incrementing the `total_p` value by 1? It should first check the previous value then increment by 1.

My controller code

```
$present = Input::get($student->id);
if ($present == 1)
    {
        DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)->where('studid', $student->id)
            ->where('smonth', $date_exploded[1])
            ->where('syear', $date_exploded[2])
            ->where('stotal_p', 1)
            ->update(array(
                'stotal_p' => 1 + 1,
            ));
        DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)->where('studid', $student->id)
            ->where('smonth', $date_exploded[1])
            ->where('syear', $date_exploded[2])
            ->where('stotal_p', 0)
            ->update(array(
                'stotal_p' => 1,
                'stotal_a' => 0,
            ));
    } elseif ($present == 0)
    {
        DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)->where('studid', $student->id)
            ->where('smonth', $date_exploded[1])
            ->where('syear', $date_exploded[2])
            ->where('stotal_a', 1)
            ->update(array(
                'stotal_a' => 1 + 1,
            ));
        DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)->where('studid', $student->id)
            ->where('smonth', $date_exploded[1])
            ->where('syear', $date_exploded[2])
            ->where('stotal_a', 0)
            ->update(array(
                'stotal_a' => 1,
            ));
        DB::table($wys_total_attend_table)->where('studid', $student->id)
            ->where('smonth', $date_exploded[1])
            ->where('syear', $date_exploded[2])
            ->where('stotal_p', 1)
            ->where('stotal_a', 0)
            ->update(array(
                'stotal_a' => 0 + 1,
            ));
    }
```

Comment: `UPDATE db1.student_attendance_table SET total_p = total_p+1 WHERE studid IN (20,21,22) AND smonth=8 AND syear=2015`?

Comment: What's the `array()` for? I doubt it's needed here (if your table design is what you have shown us).